# I2C Interface is not working on STNRG388A

Tags: i2c

I am trying to communicate with MAX30205 using STLUX385/STNRG388A.
I'm using STM8S standard peripheral libraries to communicate with I2C bus.
For STNRG388A device drivers, I'm using STLUX385 drivers provided by ST.
I can read/write GPIOs, UART communication successfully.
But when i tried the I2C bus communication, it's not working as expected.
My main.c code is below, rest of the task is in the stlux_it.c in `INTERRUPT_HANDLER(I2C_IRQHandler,19)`

```
void main ( void )
{
    // work with HSI at maximum frequency
    CLK_HSIPrescalerConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_HSIDIV1);        
    // enable PLL - Used by the SMED
    CLK_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
    while((CLK->PLLR & CLK_PLLR_LOCKP) == 0);

    // initialize the GPIO registers
    GPIO_Init(GPIO1, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);
    GPIO_Init(GPIO1, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);

    I2C_DeInit();
    CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_I2C, ENABLE);
    I2C_Cmd(ENABLE);
    I2C_Init(I2C_SPEED, SLAVE_ADDRESS, I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2, I2C_ACK_CURR, I2C_ADDMODE_7BIT,16);// (CLK_GetClockFreq()/1000000));
    I2C_ITConfig((I2C_IT_TypeDef)(I2C_IT_EVT | I2C_IT_BUF), ENABLE);
    rim();
    /* TXBuffer initialization */
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; i++)
        TxBuffer[i] = i;
    I2C_GenerateSTART(ENABLE);
    while (NumOfBytes);
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_FLAG_BUSBUSY));
    /* Add a delay to be sure that communication is finished */
    Delay(0xFFFF);

    while(1);
}
```

I have checked the MAX30205 with arduino and it's working fine.
Waiting for any positive response.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: It's not working "as expected"... well how _is_ it working? What the heck is `NumOfBytes` and how does it change values?

Comment: NumOfBytes = 10, the code is sending 10 bytes in the Buffer on the I2C lines in Master mode. But it get's stuck at while(NumOfBytes).

Comment: where is the code that you believe decrements NumOfBytes down to 0? Also where is NumOfBytes even declared?

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments, i got the I2C interface working, it was issue with the Pins(Pin 17, Pin 18) I was using.
We need to configure these pins in ADX & ADD registers to be used as I2C lines.

Answer (score 1):

We need to configure STNRG388A registers for using Pin 17(SDA) & Pin 18(SCL) as I2C lines.
This can be done using the below code in I2C_Init()

```
//define SDA, SCL outputs, HiZ, Open drain, Fast
GPIO_Init(GPIO1, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST); // Pin 17
GPIO_Init(GPIO1, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST); // Pin 18
MSC->IDXADD = ((u8)0x13);
MSC->IDXDAT = ((u8)MSC_IOMXP2_SEL_P54 & (u8)0x20);
```

Below line should be added in stlux385.h

```
#define MSC_IOMXP2_SEL_P54      ((u8)0x30) /*!< Port2[5:4] I/O multiplexing scheme */
```